# Allow vagrant to access host internet

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Im using `virtualbox + ubuntu + vagrant`. 
However im not able to `ping` or `wget` any url. Please guide me on how I can allow  the VM to access my host machine's internet?

Comment: Can you paste your vagrant configuration on Github as a gist and I could perhaps help. You can also check the /etc/resolv.conf file on the VM to see what the VM is using as a nameserver lookup.

Answer (score 5):

this works for me.
Configure the Vagrantfile with this.

```
config.vm.provider :virtualbox do |vb|

     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnshostresolver1", "on"]
     vb.customize ["modifyvm", :id, "--natdnsproxy1", "on"]
end
```

I hope this help.